# Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have function which return json data

```
transformResponse : function(data) {
   return JSON.parse(data).results;
 }
```

When function call it getting error

> Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the
>   JSON data

If their is no data then JSON.parse(data).results [ ] empty. 
I think the error is due to this [ ] object

So how to check is return empty is json or not??

Comment: Can you provide an example of data you're trying to parse? Maybe it's not valid and can not be parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test the return of json parse before you try to access to an element
// edit, added test

```
var transformResponse  = function(data){
    if(( typeof data !== undefined) && ( typeof data !== 'undefined') && ( data !== null ) && (data !== "")){
        var d = JSON.parse(data) ;

        if(( typeof d !== undefined)&&(d!=null)){
            return d.results;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }else{
        return null;
    }

};
```

Comment: Thanks @Alainkb getting same on this line `var d = JSON.parse(data);`
When i print data it got a html

Comment: paste the data you try to parse

Comment: in one case i got data is html code so it getting the error on that html code

Comment: and it gives error different in chrome browser **SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

Comment: paste the data you try to parse. if you try to parse html code of course it won't work ! why did you want to parse the data specially if it's html ?

Comment: How to check if data is html??

Comment: try this `transformResponse : function(data) {  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
 }` and paste the result you get on the console !

Comment: Thanks @AlainIb i have fixed issue

Answer (score 0):

```
transformResponse : function(data) {
   var responseData = JSON.parse(data);
   return (responseData && responseData.results) ? responseData.results:null;
 }
```

> if responseData does'nt have results or empty it will return null else
>   results array.